# Downward Löwenheim-Skolem Theorem

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Anyone out there who can help me with this little question? I am not sure how to proceed.

What happens to the Downward Löwenheim-Skolem Theorem if we consider the language L* obtained from FOL= by allowing uncountably many constants?

Comment: What do you mean by "What happens to"?

Answer (score 2):

The downward theorem will not get you down below the cardinality of the *language*, so at best you will get model of the same size as the number of constants you've added.

Comment: Specifically, to the OP: think about the theory saying that the constant symbols name distinct objects ...